# How to handle changed data type in Android DB onUpgrade()

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Example, on my
DB version 1:
my TEST_TABLE 
COLUMN_ID + INT_TYPE

DB version 2: I changed the data type to TEXT
COLUMN_ID + TEXT_TYPE

Now I want to handle this on my onUpgrade() method, I want to make sure that the datas are still there.
How to achieve this? Does altering also works for this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can't changes existing data type on sqlite, you need to create a temporary table first.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TEST_TABLE (COLUMN_ID TEXT);
INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST_TABLE (COLUMN_ID TEXT) FROM TEST_TABLE;
DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE;
ALTER TABLE TEMP_TEST_TABLE RENAME TO TEST_TABLE;
```